# Only one user can open admin.ctp file

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to do a page, and this page can open only one user. I want to do something like this: If user id = 1 then its opening else its throwing error.

I already tried this :

```
if (in_array($this->action, array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin'))) {
        $postId = (int) $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        if ($this->User->isOwnedBy($postId, $users['id'] = 1)) {

            return true;
        }else{echo "You are not admin!";}

    }
```

Then I thinked, maybe this is a little bit easier ?

```
public function admin($id = null) {

            $this->User->id = $id;
                if ($id == 1) {
                    echo 'You are admin';
                }
                else {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('You are not admin !'));
                }
        }
```

But its not working, How I get this user id in to this if. This second solution throwing only this error, but I dont want it, I want access if user id is 1.

Here is users picture

[image]

Thank you for any clue or solution.

Comment: What error you are getting?Match the id with session data. are you using auth component?

Comment: I getting this error : `else {throw new NotFoundException(__('You are not admin !'));}`

Comment: are you using auth component for login?

Comment: You mean this ? : `if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }`

Comment: Added an answer. You can check that out for logged in user.

Comment: Why not using a role based approach instead of (magic) userid numbers? That would keep the stuff out of the controllers and those lean, it would also make it more flexible to have such an admin role and a list of actions this role can access. And it's transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
public function admin($id = null) {
   $currentUserId = $this->Auth->user(id);
   //$isAdmin       = $this->User->hasAny(
      //array('User.id' => $currentUserId)
   //);
   //if ($isAdmin) {
   if ($currentUserId == 1)
       echo 'You are admin';
   } else {
       throw new NotFoundException(__('You are not admin !'));
   }
}
```

For logged in users.

Comment: I need for user with id 1, atm all logged in users can open this file, but I dont want this .

Comment: ohh... forgot that..updating the answer.

Comment: Nice, its working, but get one notice : `Notice (8): Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 88]`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach for getting logged in user data is via the AuthComponent itself:

```
// in any controller
$userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

See [Accessing the logged in user](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)Accessing the logged in user in the Auth section of the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

Comment: Yea, I have this if user is logged in, then he can open this. But I want, only user with id 1 can open this

Answer (score 0):

Better Option:-

use role id for admins, this will help you for multiple admins. and give negative id to admin:-
like add `role_id` column in user table and give value to `-1`

```
public function admin($id = null) {
   $role = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id');
   if ($role < 0)
       echo 'You are admin';
   } else {
       throw new NotFoundException(__('You are not admin !'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

so you want to check if the user ID is 1 ??

```
//Fetch the user informations from database and stock it into $user

if(is_admin($user[id])){
    echo 'You are admin';
}
else{
    echo 'You are not admin';
}

function is_admin($id = NULL){
    if($id == 1){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

tell me if I misunderstood

Edit :
According to our chat, try this :

```
//Fetch the ID of the user and stock it in $user_id

if($user_id == 1){
    echo 'You are admin';
}
else{
    echo 'You are not admin';
}
```

Comment: And how you are getting the `$user`?

Comment: by fetching it from the database. I don't put the details of it because this is not the subject. He wants to know how to verify if the user is an admin, not how to fetch datas from a database... imo...

Comment: Its not working, getting error : `Error: Call to undefined function is_admin()`

Comment: did you put all those lines in the same file ? If not, did you include the file with the function ?

Comment: new edit, new error : `Error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)`

Comment: haven't you forgot a ';' at the line above ? or something like that ?